# Impala - Grouping By Week

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

This is the example of the data i have:

[image]

This is the output i need(**grouping the total number of logins by week(sunday to saturday**):

[image]

I tried couple of queries but it did not worked out. Thanks for helping me. I am using Impala for this.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - thanks! OP - Please include your sample data as markdown tables, not images. What have you tried? What didn't work out? [WEEKOFYEAR()](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__weekofyear) The documentation does not state what it uses as the start day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `trunc()` to get a monday of the week and then use it to group by the data.

```
select trunc(login_dt, 'DAY') - interval '1' day as Sunday_of_week,
sum(num_of_logins) total_logins
from mytable)rs
group by 1
```

trunc(dt, 'DAY') - Returns starting day of the week (Monday)

hive only solution -

```
select next_day(date_sub(dt, 7), 'SUN') as Sunday_of_week,
sum(l) total_logins
from t rs where dt is not null
group by  next_day(date_sub(dt, 7), 'SUN') ;
```

output -
[image]

Comment: Yes i can use that function, but I want to start the first day as a Sunday of the week(so from sunday to saturday)

Comment: i added -1 to calculate Sunday_of_week. Could you pls check?

Comment: No this is not working

Comment: Actually i dont have any way to validate in Impala( lost access) so i posted a solution for  hive.